# Audio player on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-audio, mobile-website

I'm a total beginner and I try to use this to make an audio player

```
<audio id="music" controls>
<source src="sample.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

but on mobile websites only a play button is showed (I can't insert a picture but on desktop we will see a normal player which consists of slider).

So how can I make the player appear on mobile just like its appearance on desktop?

Answer (score 0):

It won't work. In plain HTML Simulated user interactions doesn't work in mobile.

Add a little javascript

```
 window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
        var source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'audio-autoplay.wav');
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.addEventListener('load', function (r) {
            audioCtx.decodeAudioData(
                    xhr.response, 
                    function (buffer) {
                        source.buffer = buffer;
                        source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
                        source.loop = false;
                    });
            source.start(0);
        });
        xhr.send();
    });
```